# Match columns of unequal length

Tags: r

I have two data frames with multiple columns. One of DF columns - `A` contains repeated words

```
A
cat
dog
shark
mouse
shark
dog
cat
```

In another DF - `B`, i have two columns

```
B
a     b
cat   animal-a
dog   animal-b
shark animal-c
mouse  animal-d
```

I am trying to achieve the following output

```
 A
    a      b
    cat   animal-a
    dog   animal-b
    shark animal-c
    mouse animal-d
    shark animal-c
    dog   animal-b
    cat   animal-a
```

How can i do it? i was thinking about cat with unequal columns but it did nothing. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: `A$b <- B$b[match(A$a,B$a)]`, given the first column is also called `a` in `data.frame` `A`.

Comment: @mtoto Thank you for help. Ops sorry, will correct the title.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved using *merge*, but you will lose the order of the table. The solution given by **mtoto** will preserve order.

```
merge(B, A, by.x = 'a', by.y = 'A')
```

gives :

```
      a        b
1   cat animal-a
2   cat animal-a
3   dog animal-b
4   dog animal-b
5 mouse animal-d
6 shark animal-c
7 shark animal-c
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name the column in DF1 as "a"

```
 colnames(DF)[1] <- "a"
```

and then you can use `merge`

```
 merge(DF1, DF2,all.x=T)
```